# Why eval can't be used as a variable under strict mode

Tags: javascript, eval

I was trying to execute the below code where I declared **eval** as variable.

```
(function(){
   "use strict";
    var eval = 2;
}());
```

but this throws below error,

> /* Exception: SyntaxError: 'eval' can't be defined or assigned to in
>   strict mode code @Scratchpad/1:3
>   */

But again I am able to execute the below code without any errors,

```
(function(){
   "use strict";
    var parseInt = 2;
}());
```

So my doubt is why this behaviour is specific to **eval**?

Comment: Using keywords or redeclaring system functions names as variables is bad practice and can lead to such errors.

Comment: Yeah sure, but i was just looking for the reason which is available as part of the original question